# Store variable in another variable

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to store the contents of my one variable in my for loop in my other variable, but I get

```
0403-006 Execute permission denied
```

Help.

```
while IFS='|' read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
do 
for f in directory/*
    do
        files=$($f | awk -F "_" '{print $3}')
        echo $files
    done
done <test.txt
```

I have full permissions to run this, it errors when I put in the echo $files

Comment: Are you parsing the file name which is looped with `$f`? if it so, try `files=$( echo "$f" | awk -F "_" '{print $3}')`

Comment: This is probably related to your other recent questions, right? What is it you want to do here? Don't you want to use the variables that you've just read from `test.txt`? Is the end result a filename (or pattern?) that you construct from `col1` etc.? What should that name/pattern look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450068/116858), it is clearer what it is that you actually would want to do.

Here is my own take on that:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

dupsfile='/archival/test/sppark/dataindex/staging/duplicates.txt'

indir='/archival/test/sppark/datapdf/staging/renamedTriage'
baddir='/archival/test/sppark/datapdf/staging/badFiles'

dups=$( mktemp )
cut -d '|' -f 4 <"$dupsfile" >"$dups"

for pathname in "$indir"/*; do
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue

    string=$( printf '%s\n' "${pathname##*/}" | cut -d '_' -f 4 )

    if grep -qxF "$string" "$dups" then
        echo mv "$pathname" "$baddir"
    fi
done

rm "$dups"
```

The difference between your own answer and this is that the file list is only generated once and not once per line in the data file.

The data file is parsed in such a way that its 4th `|`-delimited column is extracted and saved into a temporary file.  This file is consulted once for each file in the directory that you are investigating, using `grep`.  If the 4th `_`-delimited bit of the filename is present in that temporary file, the file is moved. Remove the `echo` to actually move files.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unclear what your script is doing and looks miswritten altogether. You need to provide more details to find out what exactly is wrong and what you want to achieve. My guess is that the error comes from this line:

```
files=$($f | awk -F "_" '{print $3}')
```

In particular, you need to realise what happens here:

```
$f | awk -F "_" '{print $3}'
```

You're executing `$f`, which is one of the files `directory/*`. One of them is `0403-006`, and you can't execute it.

What about the variables `col1`, `col2`, etc? The data read from `test.txt` is completely unused.

Present a minimal and complete example with input data and expected output, as this script doesn't look sane even if my guess is right.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified my script to do exactly what I want

```
while IFS='|' read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
do 
    for f in /archival/test/sppark/datapdf/staging/renamedTriage/*
    do
        files=$(echo "$f" | awk -F "_" '{print $4}')
        if [[ $col4 == $files ]]; then
            mv $f /archival/test/sppark/datapdf/staging/badFiles/
        fi
    done
done </archival/test/sppark/dataindex/staging/duplicates.txt
```

My while loop reads my txt file, reads each column delimited by |.  I have a for loop to loop through each file in my directory, and if my `$col4` is the same as the `$files`, it will then move the file to my specified directory